# Android file opener for json files only (Java)

Tags: android, json, android-intent, file-access, filefilter

I've got a quite simple problem but I can't find the solution...
I would like to have a file picker for my Android app where the user can select only json files.
Following works for all files:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");

startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

But how can I restrict it to files with "json" endings?
I tried something like `intent.setType("text/*")` or `intent.setType("text/json")` that did not work.
I also tried different things with `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);` where mimetypes is a Sring[] that also did not work.
It should actually be quite simple, but I can't find the solution :(

Comment: Try `application/json`, as that is the official MIME type for JSON.

Comment: That does not work. I tried `intent.setType("application/json")` as well as `intent.setType("*/*"); String[] mimetypes = {"application/json"}; intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);`. The json files are not selectable.